# In Google Cloud Vision API, how to detect if an image is the recaptured image from LCD/LED display?

Tags: image-processing, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

Is there any way in Google OCR to detect if the captured image is not the original one and recaptured from a digital display (mobile screen, laptop screen)?

Below is a sample image which is not the original image, it has been captured from the screen of a laptop.
[image]

Can we detect this colored halo pattern in the Google Cloud Vision API and mark this image as an recaptured one?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern interference between the display's grid and the camera sensor's grid

Comment: This could be a case for a 2D spectrum by FFT to detect the screen pattern.

Comment: Currently there is no option in Cloud Vision API to detect if the captured image is not the original one and is recaptured from a digital display screen. If you want this feature to be enabled, you can open a new feature request on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your requirement.